# Populate Tabulator table from PHP page containing JSON

Tags: tabulator

I am new to programming and tabulator. I have a PHP page that is displaying my JSON result.  I simply want to view this result in a tabulator table on a different page.

The JSON result is formatted like this, it is on a page called **proxystatus.php**.

```
{ "0": {
    "hostid": "10610",
    "proxy_hostid": "10609",
    "host": "PIDMPRX-DEV",
    "status": "0",
    "disable_until": "0",
    "error": "",
    "available": "1",
    "errors_from": "0",
    "lastaccess": "0",
    "ipmi_authtype": "-1",
    "ipmi_privilege": "2",
    "ipmi_username": "",
    "ipmi_password": "",
    "ipmi_disable_until": "0",
    "ipmi_available": "0",
    "snmp_disable_until": "0",
    "snmp_available": "1",
    "maintenanceid": "0",
    "maintenance_status": "0",
    "maintenance_type": "0",
    "maintenance_from": "0",
    "ipmi_errors_from": "0",
    "snmp_errors_from": "0",
    "ipmi_error": "",
    "snmp_error": "",
    "jmx_disable_until": "0",
    "jmx_available": "0",
    "jmx_errors_from": "0",
    "jmx_error": "",
    "name": "0955-PIDM-PRX",
    "flags": "0",
    "templateid": "0",
    "description": "0955\ \ Company Name",
    "tls_connect": "1",
    "tls_accept": "1",
    "tls_issuer": "",
    "tls_subject": "",
    "tls_psk_identity": "",
    "tls_psk": "",
    "proxy_address": "",
    "auto_compress": "1"
}}
```

My tabulator table code is as follows, it is on a page called **dash.php**

```
var table = new Tabulator("#proxyStatus", {
    height:"100%",
    layout:"fitColumns",
    placeholder:"Gathering Proxy Status...", 
        data:'<?=$proxyStatus?>',
        columns:[
            {title:"Status", field:"status", sorter:"string", width:200},
            {title:"Available", field:"available", sorter:"number", formatter:"progress"},
            {title:"Last Access", field:"lastaccess", sorter:"string"},
            {title:"Name", field:"name", formatter:"star", align:"center", width:100},
            {title:"Maintenance Status", field:"maintenance_status", sorter:"string", sortable:false},
            {title:"Maintenance Type", field:"maintenance_type", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
            {title:"Maintenance ID", field:"maintenanceid", align:"center", formatter:"tickCross", sorter:"boolean"},
        ],
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add all the columns in the columns array or just use     autoColumns:true in the Constructor as mentioned [here](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/columns#autocolumns) i made this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dota2pro/zyakfnu4/3/) for you to understand

```
const table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  height: 205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
  data: tabledata1, //assign data to table
  layout: "fitData", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
  autoColumns: true,

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.  I tried your code and still am getting an error.  Could you breifly explain how to access the JSON data from the other page?  Currently I am simply using <?=VARIABLENAME?> to pull the values into the other page, however, this is just showing as "Array"  If I try to print the array to it does show, however it is not using it as the table data?

Comment: Said another way, my data source is coming from a different page that is creating a json response from an api.  I need that to be my datasource.  Sorry for my ignorance, I am learning this on the fly. :-)

Comment: Here is my php page that is getting the JSON response.  I think this is where my mistake is'''

<?php
//include "pulse.php";
$proxyStatus = json_readable_encode ( pulseProxyStatus ( $uri, $authtoken ) );

$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "10";
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
?>
<script>
const tableData = new Tabulator("#proxyStatus", {
  data: <?=$proxyStatus?>, //assign data to table
  layout: "fitData", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
  autoColumns: true,
</script>

Comment: As far as I know PHP runs on a server Javascript Runs on Client(browser) you need to send the data from PHP to Javascript like a Rest API call and then run the code